# Select in the IF condition statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select, if-statement

I want to put in the if condition select query:

```
IF ( 10 in (select id from ids where ..) ) then ...
/*  */
END IF;
```

How can implement that in the correct syntax ?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: @JW: actually SQL is the basis for a RDBMS.

Comment: This looks like a procedural language syntax. What exactly do you want to do and in which RDBMS?

Comment: @nabil, can you confirm whether this is oracle or sql server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server then the obvious way is to use [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx), e.g.

```
if exists(select id from ids where id = 10)
begin
    print 'it exists'
end
```

An alternative is to use the equivalent keywords [SOME or ANY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175064.aspx)

```
if 10 = some(select id from ids)
begin
    print 'it exists'
end
```

Comment: @Phil-This is not Oracle SQL valid syntax. There is no IF in Oracle SQL. Please revise it.

Comment: @Art - the original post didn't have the Oracle tag, however the OP has accepted this - perhaps the tag should be changed.

Comment: @Phil-Then I got downvoted for nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

This may help - all examples are equiv to IF in Oracle SQL.

CASE Expressions:

```
SELECT deptno, empno, ename
     , (CASE WHEN deptno = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) check_dept
  FROM scott.emp
ORDER BY 1
/
```

DECODE() function:

```
SELECT deptno, empno, ename, DECODE(deptno, 10, 1, 0) check_dept
  FROM scott.emp
ORDER BY 1
/
```

Your example - CASE..:

```
select id, (CASE WHEN id = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS check_id from ids where... 
/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for ( -- 
      -- The following select statement returns
      -- records only, if there are any whose
      -- ID = 10.
      -- The rownum = 1 condition makes sure that
      -- at most one record is returned.
      --
      select null 
       from ids
      where id = 10 and
            rownum = 1) loop

      /* 
         Do something if at least on record is selected
         by the select statement.
       */

end loop;
```

While this "solution" should do what you want, I don't necessarily recommend to do it like so because it might not be intrinsically clear for a later maintainer of the code what the purpose if this `for ... loop` exactly was. You might want to consider using a variable into which you select the count of the records with `id=10` and do your thing based upon `cnt>0`.